# MongoDB - ."findOneAndDelete is not a function" error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

On my server I have the following code:

```
const Review = require('../models/reviewModel');

api.delete('/reviews/:reviewID', deleteReviewAndComments); 

// Delete a Review and all it's comments
const deleteReviewAndComments = async (req, res) => {
  let { reviewID } = req.params;
  reviewID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(reviewID);
  try {
    await Comment.deleteMany({ reviewID }); // Delete the Comments    
    let deletedReview = await Review.findOneAndDelete({ _id: reviewID }); // Delete the Review
    res.json(deletedReview);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error deleting review and comments ${e}`);
    res.status(403).send(e);
  }
}
```

This request handler is meant to take in an ObjectId (reviewID), find a review with that id, delete it and return the deleted data. However, when I run this i keep getting this error:

```
Error deleting review and comments TypeError: Review.findOneAndDelete is not a function
```

I have checked and verified that a valid objectId is being sent.

Comment: Which mongoose and MongoDB versions do you use?

Comment: you are probably using lower mongoose version i.e. > 4.x. Use `findOneAndRemove`

Answer (score 1):

findOneandDelete is applicable for mongoose versions 5.X & 6.X as present in their docs. For versions less than 5.X, you can use findOneandRemove.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/api.html

Answer (score 0):

`findOneAndDelete()` is valid as stated in [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndDelete), hence, it is most likely you aren't exporting the model object as the default.

```
// ../models/reviewModel.js

let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // fields here
});

// We export the model as the default
module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', reviewSchema);
```

Comment: Yes I am. I have used this `Review` model in some other handlers. And they all work fine

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const user = await User.findOne({email : req.body.email})
if(!user){
  return res.status(404).send("User not found!")
}
await User.deleteOne({ email:req.body.email });

res.status(200).send("User deleted Successfully");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).